# GoogleSign in error only on Xiomi Devices

Tags: android, google-play-services

Using ***com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:10.0.1*** for google signin in android app and its not working on **xiomi** devices and on other devices its working.

**Stacktrace** :

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.myapp/com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.internal.SignInHubActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Bad magic number for Bundle: 0xffff4f45
       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2332)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2394)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:154)
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1308)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5276)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:911)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:706) Caused by java.lang.IllegalStateException: Bad magic number for Bundle: 0xffff4f45
       at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1554)
       at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1499)
       at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.startActivity(ActivityManagerNative.java:2441)
       at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1500)
       at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3796)
       at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3757)
       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(SourceFile:842)
       at com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.internal.SignInHubActivity.zzj(Unknown Source)
       at com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.internal.SignInHubActivity.onCreate(Unknown Source)
       at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6041)
       at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1109)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2285)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2394)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:154)
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1308)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5276)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:911)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:706)
```

Comment: Have you implemented it as [Parcelable?](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html), can you share with us some code snippets with regards to your implementation?

Comment: com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.internal.SignInHubActivity activity is throwing error , compiled code .